# How to add years in a date column?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    code,
    date_format(first_date, '%d/%m/%Y'),
    date_format(last_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
FROM
    export
```

If I alter the 4th line to:

```
date_add(date_format(last_date, '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
```

and get NULL as result.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

PS.: first_date and last_date are "date" type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your function calls around so you *first* add the 5 years and *then* format the new date:

```
date_format(date_add(last_date, INTERVAL 5 YEAR), '%d/%m/%Y')
```